# How can I request that a font be added to the official repositories?

Tags: fonts, official-repositories

I think it would be beneficial to have the [Cardo](http://scholarsfonts.net/cardofnt.html) font included in Ubuntu's official repositories.

Where can I make this kind of request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll almost certainly want to [get this font into Debian first](http://wiki.debian.org/FontsTaskForce).  By doing so, you'll save resources on the packaging maintenance, since it nearly always [will flow into Ubuntu automatically through Debian](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SyncRequestProcess).

Comment: Thanks, that was just the right pointer. Looks like someone is [already on it](http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/pkg-fonts-devel/2010-May/005025.html). [Info](http://rb.doesntexist.org/blog/posts/packaging-fonts-for-a-debian-based-system/) and [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~rbrito/+archive/ppa/).